# How to shoot bullets at the same time as another player and easier method on creating boundaries between rectangles and players?

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a 2D game and I am having some problems with my code. First of all, my players cannot fire bullets at the same time at each. Also, is their an easier method or function to create a boundary between my two players and the rectangles on screen, or would I just have to use pyagame.Rect.collidepoint() for points on the outside of the rectangle, and if a player collides with a rectangle I would say:
`if keystate[pygame.K_w] and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint():
            self.y_change = -5`

main code:

```
import OpenGL
import panda3d
import pygame
import pyglet
import tkinter
import time
import random

pygame.init()
display_width = 1200
display_height = 600

green = (0, 255, 0)
yellow = (255, 255, 0)
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

person_height = 113
person_width = 150
person2_width = 150
person2_height = 113


gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Wert')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

personImg = pygame.image.load('Untitled.png').convert_alpha()
personImg2 = pygame.image.load('Untitled2.png').convert_alpha()
bulletImg = pygame.image.load('Untitled1.png').convert_alpha()

player_health = 100
player2_health = 100
x = (0)
y = (display_height * 0.37)
ny = (display_height * 0.37)
nx = (display_width * 0.87)
thing_width = 100
thing_height = 100





class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
 def __init__(self):
     pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
     self.image = personImg
     self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
     self.rect.x = x
     self.rect.y = y
     self.player_health = 100
     self.x_change = 0
     self.y_change = 0


 def update(self):
     self.x_change = 0
     self.y_change = 0
     keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
     if keystate[pygame.K_w] and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/2, player2.rect.y + person2_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/4, player2.rect.y + person2_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width - 10, player2.rect.y + person2_height):
         self.y_change = -5
     if keystate[pygame.K_s] and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/2, player2.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/4, player2.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width - 10, player2.rect.y):
         self.y_change = 5
     if keystate[pygame.K_d] and pygame.key.get_mods() and pygame.KMOD_LSHIFT and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height - 10):
         self.x_change = 10
     elif keystate[pygame.K_d] and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x, player2.rect.y + person2_height - 10):
         self.x_change = 5
     if keystate[pygame.K_a] and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width, player2.rect.y + person2_height - 10):
         self.x_change = -5
     self.rect.x += self.x_change
     self.rect.y +=self.y_change
     if self.rect.right > display_width:
         self.rect.right = display_width
     if self.rect.left < 0:
         self.rect.left = 0
     if self.rect.top < 0:
         self.rect.top = 0
     if self.rect.bottom > display_height:
         self.rect.bottom = display_height


 def shoot(self):
     bullet = Bullet1(self.rect.x, self.rect.y)
     all_sprites.add(bullet)
     bullets.add(bullet)





class Player2(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
 def __init__(self):
     pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
     self.image = personImg2
     self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
     self.rect.x = nx
     self.rect.y = ny
     self.player2_health = 100
     self.x_change1 = 0
     self.y_change1 = 0

 def update(self):
     self.x_change1 = 0
     self.y_change1 = 0
     keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
     if keystate[pygame.K_UP] and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width/2, player.rect.y + person_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width/4, player.rect.y + person_height) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width - 10, player.rect.y + person_height):
         self.y_change1 = -5
     if keystate[pygame.K_DOWN] and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width/2, player.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width/4, player.rect.y) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width - 10, player.rect.y):
         self.y_change1 = 5
     if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT] and pygame.key.get_mods() and pygame.KMOD_RSHIFT and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width, player.rect.y + person_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width, player.rect.y + person_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width, player.rect.y + person_height - 10):
         self.x_change1 = -10
     elif keystate[pygame.K_LEFT] and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width, player.rect.y + person_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width, player.rect.y + person_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x + person_width, player.rect.y + person_height - 10):
         self.x_change1 = -5
     if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT] and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x, player.rect.y + person_height/2) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x, player.rect.y + person_height/4) and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player.rect.x, player.rect.y + person_height - 10):
         self.x_change1 = 5
     self.rect.x += self.x_change1
     self.rect.y += self.y_change1
     if self.rect.right > display_width:
         self.rect.right = display_width
     if self.rect.left < 0:
         self.rect.left = 0
     if self.rect.top < 0:
         self.rect.top = 0
     if self.rect.bottom > display_height:
         self.rect.bottom = display_height

 def shoot(self):
     bullet = Bullet(self.rect.x, self.rect.y)
     all_sprites.add(bullet)
     bullets1.add(bullet)



all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
player2 = Player2()
bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullets1 = pygame.sprite.Group()


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
 def __init__(self, x, y):
     pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
     self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 10))
     self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(gameDisplay)
     self.image.fill(black)
     self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
     self.rect.x = x
     self.rect.y = y
     self.x_change = -10


 def update(self):
     self.rect.x += self.x_change
     if self.rect.left > display_width:
         self.kill()
     if self.rect.right < 0:
         self.kill()

class Bullet1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
 def __init__(self, x, y):
     pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
     self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 10))
     self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(gameDisplay)
     self.image.fill(black)
     self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
     self.rect.x = x
     self.rect.y = y
     self.x_change1 = 10

 def update(self):
     self.rect.x += self.x_change1
     if self.rect.left > display_width:
         self.kill()
     if self.rect.right < 0:
         self.kill()


bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
players1 = pygame.sprite.Group()
players2 = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullet1 = Bullet1(x, y)
players1.add(player)
players2.add(player2)
bullet = Bullet(x, y)
all_sprites.add(player)
all_sprites.add(player2)


def person(x, y):
 gameDisplay.blit(personImg, (x, y))



def person2(nx,ny):
 gameDisplay.blit(personImg2, (nx, ny))


#def boundary():
 #if x > thing_startx and x < thing_startx + thing_width or x + person_width > thing_startx and x + person_width < thing_startx + thing_width:
 #if x > display_width - person_width or x < 0:

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
 mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
 click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
 if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
     pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))

     if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
         action()
 else:
     pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))

 smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("timesnewromanms",20)
 textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
 textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
 gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def died():

 GameOver = True

 while GameOver:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             pygame.quit()
             quit()

     gameDisplay.fill(white)
     redrawgame()
     largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("timesnewromanms", 115)
     TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Player 2 wins", largeText)
     TextRect.center = ((display_width / 2), (display_height / 2))
     gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

     button("Play Again", 450, 450, 100, 50, blue, blue, game_loop)
     button("Quit", 650, 450, 100, 50, red, red, quitgame)

     pygame.display.update()
     clock.tick(15)

def died1():


 GameOver = True

 while GameOver:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             pygame.quit()
             quit()

     gameDisplay.fill(white)
     redrawgame()
     largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("timesnewromanms", 115)
     TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Player 1 wins", largeText)
     TextRect.center = ((display_width / 2), (display_height / 2))
     gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

     button("Play Again", 450, 450, 100, 50, blue, blue, game_loop)
     button("Quit", 650, 450, 100, 50, red, red, quitgame)

     pygame.display.update()
     clock.tick(15)



def health_bars(player_health, player2_health):

 if player_health > 75:
     player_health_color = green
 elif player_health > 50:
     player_health_color = yellow
 else:
     player_health_color = red
 if player2_health > 75:
     player2_health_color = green
 elif player2_health > 50:
     player2_health_color = yellow
 else:
     player2_health_color = red
 pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, player2_health_color, (1080, 25, player2_health, 25))
 pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, player_health_color, (20, 25, player_health, 25))


def redrawgame():
 player.rect.x = x
 player.rect.y = y
 player2.rect.x = nx
 player2.rect.y = ny

def game_intro():
 intro = True

 while intro:
     for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             pygame.quit()
             quit()

     gameDisplay.fill(white)
     largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("timesnewromanms", 115)
     TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Wert", largeText)
     TextRect.center = ((display_width / 2), (display_height / 2))
     gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

     button("Play", 450, 450, 100, 50, blue, blue, game_loop)
     button("Quit", 650, 450, 100, 50, red, red, quitgame)

     pygame.display.update()
     clock.tick(15)
def quitgame():
 pygame.quit()
 quit()
def text_objects(text, font):
 textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
 return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def paused():
 largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("timesnewromanms", 115)
 TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Paused", largeText)
 TextRect.center = ((display_width / 2), (display_height / 2))
 gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

 pause = True
 while pause:
     for event in pygame.event.get():

         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             pygame.quit()
             quit()



     button("Continue", 450, 450, 100, 50, blue, blue, game_loop)
     button("Quit", 650, 450, 100, 50, red, red, quitgame)

     pygame.display.update()
     clock.tick(15)





def game_loop():
 x = (0)
 y = (display_height * 0.37)
 ny = (display_height * 0.37)
 nx = (display_width * 0.87)
 y_change = 0
 x_change = 0
 x_change1 = 0
 y_change1 = 0
 bullet1 = Bullet1(x, y)
 bullet = Bullet(x, y)
 thing_startx = display_width/2
 thing_starty = display_height/2
 thing_startx1 = display_width / 2 - thing_width
 thing_starty1 = display_height / 2 - thing_height
 thing_startx2 = display_width / 2 + thing_width + 50
 thing_starty2 = display_height / 2 + 50
 thing_startx3 = display_width - 500
 thing_starty3 = display_height - 450
 thing_startx4 = display_width - 950
 thing_starty4 = display_height - 350
 thing_startx5 = display_width - 800
 thing_starty5 = display_height - 250

 gameExit = False

 player_health = 100
 player2_health = 100

 for bullet in bullets:
     bullet.kill()
 for bullet in bullets1:
     bullet.kill()

 while not gameExit:

         for event in pygame.event.get():
             if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                 pygame.quit()
                 quit()
             if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                 if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                     player.shoot()
             if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                 player2.shoot()
             if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                 if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                     paused()



         y += y_change
         x += x_change
         ny += y_change1
         nx += x_change1



         gameDisplay.fill(white)
         block = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, (thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height))
         block1 = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, (thing_startx1, thing_starty1, thing_width, thing_height))
         block2 = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, (thing_startx2, thing_starty2, thing_width, thing_height))
         block3 = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, (thing_startx3, thing_starty3, thing_width, thing_height))
         block4 = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, (thing_startx4, thing_starty4, thing_width, thing_height))
         block5 = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, (thing_startx5, thing_starty5, thing_width, thing_height))

         block
         block1
         block2
         block3
         block4
         block5


         player
         player2


         #if x > thing_startx and x < thing_startx + thing_width or x + person_width > thing_startx and x + person_width < thing_startx + thing_width:
             #hit()

         #if thing_starty > display_height:
             #thing_starty = 0 - thing_height
             #thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)

         if pygame.Rect.colliderect(block, bullet) or pygame.Rect.colliderect(block1, bullet) or pygame.Rect.colliderect(block2, bullet) or pygame.Rect.colliderect(block3, bullet) or pygame.Rect.colliderect(block4, bullet) or pygame.Rect.colliderect(block5, bullet):
             bullet.kill()
         if pygame.Rect.colliderect(block, bullet1) or pygame.Rect.colliderect(block1, bullet1) or pygame.Rect.colliderect(block2, bullet1) or pygame.Rect.colliderect(block3, bullet1) or pygame.Rect.colliderect(block4, bullet1) or pygame.Rect.colliderect(block5, bullet1):
             bullet1.kill()



         for bullet1 in bullets1:
             if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(bullet1, player):
                 bullet1.kill()
                 player_health -= 10
                 break
         if player_health == 0:
             died()

         for bullet in bullets:
             if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(bullet, player2):
                 bullet.kill()
                 player2_health -= 10
                 break
         if player2_health == 0:
             died1()



         all_sprites.update()

         health_bars(player_health, player2_health)
         all_sprites.draw(gameDisplay)
         pygame.display.flip()

         pygame.display.update()
         clock.tick(60)


game_intro()
game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
`
```

Comment: This is somewhat unrelated to your actual question, but I would recommend that you eliminate the separate Player/Player2 classes, as well as Bullet/Bullet1. Instead, feed the Player class a list of keys, and feed the Bullet class a direction. In general, copy-pasting code is a clue that you should change the design.

Answer (score 0):

The colliderect() function can simplify player collision.

```
 if keystate[pygame.K_s] and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/2, player2.rect.y) \
         and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width/4, player2.rect.y) \
         and not pygame.Rect.collidepoint(self.rect, player2.rect.x + person2_width - 10, player2.rect.y):
```

can be simplified to

```
 if keystate[pygame.K_s] and not pygame.Rect.colliderect(self.rect, player2.rect):
```

I would put the rectangles into a list, then loop over them in a function, using the colliderect() function to check each one.

```
thing_starts.append((display_width/2, display_height/2))
thing_starts.append((display_width / 2 - thing_width, display_height / 2 - thing_height))
...
blocks = []
for thing_start in thing_starts:
    blocks.append(pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, (thing_start[0], thing_start[1], thing_width, thing_height)))
...
for block in blocks:
    if pygame.Rect.colliderect(block, bullet):
        bullet.kill()
```

(EDIT: note that list comprehension can simplify things even further, but that's a bit of an advanced move. I'll show you if you ask, though.)